# Can I still use "insert_id" with PHP commit/rollback?

Tags: php, mysqli, commit, rollback

I had a PHP application that automatically committed the insertion whenever I submitted the form. The code I used looked like this:

```
$dbConnection = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

$query = "some query here";
$queryResult = $dbConnection->query($query);
if($queryResult){
    $_SESSION['insertedID'] = $dbConnection->insert_id;
}
else{
}
```

As you can see, I used the auto_increment value as a SESSION variable. So, then I decided to add some commit/rollback protection to my application. So, I changed my code to look like this:

```
$dbConnection = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
$dbConnection->autocommit(FALSE);
$query = "some query here";
$queryResult = $dbConnection->query($query);
if($queryResult){
    $dbConnection->commit();
    $_SESSION['insertedID'] = $dbConnection->insert_id;
}
else{
    $dbConnection->rollback();
}
```

However, I have found out that the "$dbConnection->insert_id" function no longer works. Is this possible with commit/rollback in place, or am I out of luck? If this does not work with commit/rollback, is there some other way I can quickly grab the last auto_increment ID, or am I out of luck there too?

Comment: Instead of `autocommit()`, you could use `begin_transaction()` and `commit()` / `rollback()` to more eplicitly define the transaction. (This is an unrelated comment.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retrieve `$dbConnection->insert_id` **BEFORE** `commit()`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. It makes sense now that I look at.